# Get javascript variable with ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to get a javascript variable with ajax (and eventually get it to php).
I've tried several things. I'm trying to get the values of a Jquery range slider as soon as the user changes it (to save the values later on). This is the javascript:

```
$("#slider").bind("userValuesChanged", function(e, data){
  console.log( + data.values.min );
});
```

The log is outputting the right values as soon as I change the minimum slider.
Now I'm trying to get this userValuesChanged with ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "json",
   url: "test.php",
   data: "{userValuesChanged}",
   async: false,
   success: function(data){
     alert(data);
     return true;
   }
 });
```

Well as this is my first time using ajax, this is not working. I'm not sure how to write the right value at the data tag. How to get the userValuesChanged? Or the specific + data.values.minv value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `ajax` call, you're just sending the string `"{userValuesChanged}"`.

If you want to send new values, you specify those in an object:

```
$("#slider").bind("userValuesChanged", function (e, data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "test.php",
        data: { minValue: data.values.min },
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

The key bit above is:

```
data: { minValue: data.values.min },
```

...which creates an object with a property called `minValue` which is set to the value of the `data.values.min` you receive from the scroller. Your server-side script would look for a field called `minValue`. (Naturally if you also want other values from `data.values`, you can include them as well.)

---

Doing that every time the slider changes may be a bit much, though. If the `userValuesChanged` event only fires **once**, when the values have stopped changing, then the above is absolutely fine. If it fires continually when the user is moving the scroller, that wouldn't be good, because you'd be triggering a **lot** of `ajax` calls.

If that's the case (that it fires repeatedly as the user changes the value), see if it offers a different event when the user *stops* making changes.

If it doesn't, you can rate-limit instead. Here's how to do that if necessary:

```
$("#slider").bind("userValuesChanged", function (e, data) {
    saveNewValues(data.values.min);
});

var pendingSaveTimer = 0;
function saveNewValues(minValue) {
    // cancel any previous save we have pending
    clearTimeout(pendingSaveTimer);
    pendingSaveTimer = 0;

    // Schedule saving the new value in half a second
    pendingTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        // Clear our timer var
        pendingTimer = 0;

        // Do it
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "test.php",
            data: { minValue: minValue },
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                // Do something here if needed
            }
        });
    }, 500); // 500 = 500 milliseconds = half a second
}
```

That waits half a second before saving a value, and cancels that save if a new value comes in within that half a second.

Comment: IMO the interval 500 could and probably will choke the browser if the page is running for too long or if the internet connection is slow.

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov: Why would it do that? It's not polling or anything. What we're doing here is avoiding doing any work when the value changes several times within a brief period, as is likely, and then doing **one** call half a second after it stops changing.

Comment: I don't really see a need of using the timer, one could trigger the custom event on .mouseup(), cuz then is the time when the value will not be modified anytime soon (or at least in theory). With the usage of timer there r going to be unnecessary requests with same data Not arguing just expanding my knowledge :)

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov: I don't know that particular scroller's events. Certainly using a final "changed" event would be better. But I don't want people to get the impression the above is in any way a burden on the browser. It isn't. Scheduling something via `setTimeout` is trivially fast, as is cancelling it later if necessary. And again, the actual `ajax` call only happens once, when when the value stops changing.

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov: Actually, the name `userValuesChanged` could suggest that it's already only doing it once when the user is done making changes. :-) Hopefully so. I've updated the answer to clarify in any case.

Comment: Agreed on the burden :) As far as my understanding goes we just showcased a few other options that could be mixed in different ways. +1 for the responsive edits :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, the userValuesChanged is indeed only responding when the changes are finished.

Comment: @LarsKerff: I should have been able to tell that from the name. :-) Glad that helped!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How can I get the variable to php? Don't know if I need to post it with Ajax or Get it in ajax to use it in PHP..

Comment: @LarsKerff: Either works, but as you're changing state, the appropriate HTTP verb is `POST`, not `GET`. So in the above, change `type: "GET"` to `type: "POST"`, and then look for `$_POST['minValue']` in `test.php`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hm.. that's what I was trying. I tried:
`echo $_POST['minValue'];`
But that does nothing

Comment: @LarsKerff: If you've changed `type`, that should work. Mind you, you're telling jQuery you're expecting a JSON response.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Indeed it's not a JSON value so changed it to "text".. I can see the value in the `alert(data);` popup. But how can I echo it on the site? I tried:
`<?php echo 'Minimum value ' . $_POST['minValue'] . ''; ?>`

Comment: @LarsKerff: You're thinking in terms of creating a page from scratch. Return *data* in response to the `ajax` call (JSON is a good format for that), and then use that data to update the page that already exists, by interacting with the DOM. Example: `$("#elementId").text(data);` (But of course, just having the PHP echo back the data you sent it and already have cient-side already isn't very interesting; the point of an ajax call is either to send info to the server to be recorded, or to retrieve info from the server you don't already have on the client.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know.. I was just wondering how to.. Actually I'm using the range slider values so they can be saved and updated everytime someone changes the slider. If I'm right the only way to do this is with ajax right? So it communicates with js and php and store them in the database. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @LarsKerff: Yup, or you could store them in a cookie, but that would be specific to the browser rather than the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "json",
     url: "test.php",
     data: {userValuesChanged:userValuesChanged},
     async: false,
     success: function(data){
           alert(data);
          return true;
      }
 });
```

The data should be like `{key : value}` format while you sending the data through ajax

Comment: You should mention that the syntax is {key:value} :D cuz in this case it will become {1:1} which will change on every change, so one can't really know what will go to the server :P

Comment: Note that in {key:value} the value is parsed as a variable name and the key is sent as plaintext. Which is sorta counter-intuitive (or was to me when I first started working with this stuff).

Comment: It was long time since I last used AJAX, but don't the keys have to be quoted? Sorry If am wrong

Comment: @Gautam3164 wasnt me mate only suggested an edit, didn't downvoted.

Comment: No key and value can be without quotes